# Elasticsearch giving 405 method not allowed error for minio audit webhook

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, webhooks, minio

I am trying to send minio audit logs to elasticsearch using minio webhook method as described in https://min.io/docs/minio/kubernetes/upstream/operations/monitoring/minio-logging.html#id2
But I am getting 405 method not allowed error.
Our es is hosted on vm on kubernetes as node port service so I am trying with es_node_ip:node_port in endpoint becasue minio is in other cluster and es is on other cluster and both have network connectivity.
Please point me to what could be wrong